# Database design decision: normalization or repetition?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, database-design

I'm building a delivery system, by now, my design looks like that:

[image: erd]

The problem is, very frequently, I'll need a structure (array, json, objects...) that looks like that (very hierarchical):

[image: hierarchy]

The problem with this, is that it creates a lot of repetition of StreetAddress, DeliveryPoint and Customer, since each Itinerary would create lots of them and itineraries looks very much like others.
The good part is that everything would be pretty with just a few joins.

With the first schema, it would be very weird to create the second structure, but its possible.

Any ideas on how to control the repetition and still get an easy to query schema for the above structure?

I'm using:

- PostgreSQL 9.1
- PHP 5.5
- Symfony Framework Standard Edition 2.4.0-BETA1 (With Doctrine)

[In case anyone wants to know how did I draw the schemas: www.gliffy.com]

Comment: My recommendation is to go with the first schema to reduce duplication in your database.  It will save you tons of headaches later.  If you want an "easier" database layout to query, create views on top of your database tables that present the data in an easier to query manner for your application.  The more complicated queries would only need written one time in the view, and your application logic can remain simple.

Comment: Additional reading that my help you (link to another post inside of this one is also useful).  The real question is what is your motivation for NOT normalizing the data?  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal.html

Comment: @DavidF Thank you David. I'm currently going with normalization+view.

Answer (score 0):

Repetition and normalization are not always opposing questions.

Here's the basic problem:

**Normalization doesn't care about repetition per se but about functional dependency**

Repetition is the wrong question.  Functional dependency is the right question.  In some of your cases, addresses are remarkably hard to determine functional dependencies regarding because there are so many conventions out there, and even if you did, you'd still run into formatting issues.

A simple way to get to the bottom of this is asking about reasons why a given piece of data may change.  Good, normalized design limits the reasons why a given piece of data may need to change.  Now, with that in mind, it looks like you need to store historical locations for customers and it looks to me like you might want to do something slightly different.

Instead of:

```
Delivery -> customer -> street address -> itinerary
```

It looks to me like it would make more sense to:

```
Customer -> street address
```

And

```
delivery -> itinerary -> street address
```

In this model you may have duplicate information and you may need to have dates in the street address indicating when it is valid to and from, but that doesn't strike me as a normalization problem especially given the normalization problems that addresses already pose.  But from there you can easily track the customer the delivery was made to, while in your model it isn't clear you can track the street address or itinerary of a given delivery.